# Chuwi Corebook X - Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel doesn't recognise battery. Is it fixable?

Tags: kernel, power-management, battery

I bought [Chuwi Corebook X i5](https://store.chuwi.com/products/chuwi-corebook-x)-8th generation variant and after Ubuntu installation I can't check how my battery is doing, there is no battery percentage indicator. Did some digging and it seems that Ubuntu doesn't recognise my battery. In power statistics there is no battery tab and it only shows Device, type: unknown. I run `acpi` command in terminal and got: No support for device: power supply. Can you guys help me with that problem?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "can't check... battery". Does it not have show an icon representing the charge? Or you don't know which is which? Does it not show the estimated remaining time to discharge or fully charge when you click the top right menu? And have you updated UEFI already? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: [They](https://forum.chuwi.com/t/corebook-x-i5-8259u-model-battery-not-detected-under-linux/30518) don't answer to this question, others have these problems too. So obviously some proprietary device which no one cares to reverse-engineer  to get a driver for linux. I'd advice to check **first** if your hardware is supported by linux.